# What is the URL for a Java Servlet

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I opened a Maven project in IntelliJ trying to deploy a Java servlet. This is the class I wrote:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/home")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().write("Hello World");
    }
}
```

and when I do "tomcat7:redeploy", I get a message that build is successful:

```
[INFO] tomcatManager status code:200, ReasonPhrase:OK [INFO] OK -
Deployed application at context path /JavaCourse [INFO]
------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Now, I want to know what should be the URL address that I have to type in the browser to get the servlet.

I tried localhost:8080/home and I got an error. 
Can you please help me?

Comment: Maybe ` localhost:8080/JavaCourse/home`  ?

Comment: You're right!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full URL of a servlet includes the context into which the web application was deployed.

As you deployed it to `/JavaCourse` the URL of the servlet is:

```
http://localhost:8080/JavaCourse/home
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be localhost:8080/%your_project_name%/home. Not straightly localhost:8080/home.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat deployed your application to 'localhost:8080/JavaCourse/', not just 'localhost:8080/'

You should be able to access this particular servlet at localhost:8080/JavaCourse/home